# unitended reference comparision

Tags: asp.net

I am getting this warning:

`Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'`

I tried this:

```
 if (Convert.ToString(Session["message"]) == SESSIONTIMEOUT)
```

or

```
 if (Session["message"].ToString() == SESSIONTIMEOUT)
```

But I'm still getting the above message.

Comment: `Session["message"].ToString()` will throw `NullReferenceException` if the session doesn't have the `message` key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Equals method for comparison of Strings, like this:

```
if (Session["message"].ToString().Equals(SESSIONTIMEOUT))
```

Generally speaking, the == operator is supposed to perform identity comparison - i.e., verifying that two object references point at the same object. See http://www.andymcm.com/csharpfaq.htm#6.7 for more information.

Comment: throws me an error because `Session["message"]` is null - `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: i am just closing this question the above answer did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the compiler warning message carefully, it says how you should solve it:

```
if ((string)Session["message"] == SESSIONTIMEOUT)
```

That's what casting the left hand side to `string` means, and this should be the solution. The reason why the message didn't go away, is that you didn't perform a complete rebuild (recompilation) of your project.

Now if there is any change the left hand side could be an object that's not a string, then use:

```
if (Session["message"] as string == SESSIONTIMEOUT)
```

but I guess you will not allow the type of your message to be non-string, so go for my first solution, the one suggested by the warning message.